# Use physical ethernet port on vSphere client - esxi 6

Tags: ethernet, esxi

I have the following setup:

- ESXi 6.0.0 Server is accessible through a wireless accesspoint.
- On a latop I'm using the vSphere client to connect to the Server and run my VM.
- The laptop has a Raspberry PI connected to it.

I created a new vSwitch for the VM with no NIC of the server connected to it, because I want the physical ethernet port of the laptop to be "free" so it can talk to the PI. The VM has his ethernet settings set to this `VM Network`.

Just trying to `ping` the Raspberry PI, but without succes. Ofcourse I could connect the PI to the physical ethernet port of the Server, but this is not really operative.

Comment: what does the server nic have to do with the laptop nic? vSphere just connects to the ESXI server where the VM runs using the servers network connection. It does not modify the way a connecting systems NICs are assigned, used, or configured. Are all three devices using the same IP network? note that a vswitch can only be used by VMs. you cannot attach physical workstations to it.

Comment: yes, understood. All my devices are in the same network. My VM has 1 Ethernet adapter that is connected to the vSwitch, but now I want my VM to talk with the real physical port on my PC where the VM client is running. Note that I'm already connected to the server via my wireless adapter on the client.

Comment: as you describe it, there is no way to reach the virtual switch except via the VM, since it does not connect to the server port. its like you have two physical systems on two switches that are connected together, but you have unplugged the line between the two switches. Additionally, how are all the systems on the same IP network if the pi is connected to the laptop, not the AP?

Comment: yeah.. so I need to somehow bridge virtual and physical ethernet adapters.

Comment: you need to connect a "Uplink" adapter to the vswitch that links it to a physical port on the server. that way, packets from the AP can traverse the vswitch to get to the VM and viceversa. https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/virtual-networking-101-understanding-vmware-networking  https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vcli.examples.doc_50%2Fcli_manage_networks.11.4.html